# JavaScript binding Proxy getters/setters to a specific context

Tags: javascript, proxy

This might be a weird use case with no solution, but I would be happy to hear any answers on how to solve it.

Question:

I have a globally defined proxy:

```js
this.appState = {}
global.globalState = new Proxy(this.appState, {
  get: (target, prop, receiver) => {
    console.log(this) // #3
    return Reflect.get(...arguments)
  },
  set: (obj, prop, value) => {
    console.log(this) // #2
    obj[prop] = value
    return true
  }
})
```

And somewhere else I have a class:

```js
export default class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this) // #1
    global.globalState["greet"] = "hi"
    console.log(this.globalState["greet"])
  }
}
```

Is it possible to bind `this` from the class constructor to be also `this` in getter and setter of the proxy? So basically, the context of the class constructor needs to be accessed from inside of the proxy getter and setter.

Comment: Are these two pieces of code in same file? Are they in same class, cus I see ` this` in the first piece, does it points to `MyClass` instance?

Comment: @hackape That is what the question is... if it's possible to bind the class to the Proxy `this`. The current ones are the proxy instance

Comment: Yes sure. Wrap the proxy creation into a function, then `.call` it with `new MyClass`

Comment: @JonasWilms this is not exactly what I want. The proxy is created globally on sort of boot. It also will be accessed from multiple classes so creating it in a specific class is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is wether the line

```
global.globalState["greet"] = "hi"
```

can be somehow modified to change the `this` in the Proxies get method, then the answer is no. The arrow function is lexically bound (so its `this` can't change between different calls), and even if you would use a regular function instead there is still no way to call it by assigning a property, as the function is called by the runtime, and as Proxies are transparent, there is no way to influence that at all (you don't even know that the line calls a setter).

---

To dynamically change `this` you could use something like:

```
 let context = null;

 // inside the getter
 (function thisInjection() {

 }).call(context);
```

however that would require modifying the Proxies code, and in that case replacing `this` with `context` would be way easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see how it works. I just needed to hear that it is not possible because I spent some time hacking around it.